# Why does the model predict ineffectively even though the loss function is low?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I'm applying machine learning in the physics field to predict the potential of a molecule. This potential can be described as a 2d array with a shape 64*64. For convenience, I scaled the value of the potential in the range from 0 to 1.

A sample of the potential after being scaled:

[image: plot]

My goal is to build a neural network model with Keras to predict the potential. The input of the model is some physical quantities that can be treated as a 1d array and the output is the potential that I mentioned above. The results of the model after training were great, the MAPE is less than 5%, but the test phase had a big problem on both the test dataset and trainining dataset (both of the datasets have the same distribution input).

The left one is the potential that the model predicts, the middle one is the true value, and the last one this the MAPE:

[image: three plots]

I have tried many loss functions (MAE; (1-SSIM); etc.); change the model layers to improve the model,  but nothing happened.

Here is my lowest loss:

```
120/120 [==============================] - 3s 29ms/step - loss: 0.0534 - mape: 1.2858
```

The loss function:

```
def LOSS(y_true, y_pred):

    LOSS1 = K.abs(y_pred - y_true)
    LOSS1 = K.batch_flatten(LOSS1)
    LOSS1 = tf.reduce_mean(LOSS1, axis=-1)

    LOSS2 = 1 - tf.image.ssim(tf.reshape(y_true, [-1,  NyMax, NxMax, 1]),
                              tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1,  NyMax, NxMax, 1]), 1)

    return tf.math.add(3*LOSS1, 7*LOSS2)
```

The model:

```
def create_model(in_dim,x_dim,y_dim):
    H,W = int(y_dim/2), int(x_dim/2)

    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(in_dim,))  
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='tanh')(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(H*W, activation='tanh')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((H,W,1))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(4, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=(1,1), activation='selu', padding='same',
                                        kernel_regularizer=regularizers.L1(1e-4), bias_regularizer=regularizers.L1(1e-4))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)  
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(4, kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(2,2), activation='selu', padding='same',
                                        kernel_regularizer=regularizers.L1(1e-4), bias_regularizer=regularizers.L1(1e-4))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x) 
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', padding='same',
                               kernel_regularizer=regularizers.L1(1e-4), bias_regularizer=regularizers.L1(1e-4))(x)

    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((y_dim,x_dim))(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs) 
    return model
```

Can anyone explain why my model is ineffective although the loss is low and how to improve it?

The loss plot:

[image: training graphs]

Here is how I transform the input data:

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(POLY_DEGREE) # POLY_DEGREE = 4
scaler = StandardScaler()
pca = PCA(PCA_COMPONENTS) # POLY_DEGREE = 64

X = poly.fit_transform(X)
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X = pca.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably your model is over-fitting the data:

[https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/overfitting#:~:text=Overfitting%20is%20a%20concept%20in,unseen%20data%2C%20defeating%20its%20purpose](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/overfitting#:%7E:text=Overfitting%20is%20a%20concept%20in,unseen%20data%2C%20defeating%20its%20purpose).

A clear sign of over-fitting is when the *training loss* is very low, but the *validation errors* are large.

Why does this happen? Well, neural networks have so many degrees-of-freedom that in some cases, they "memorize" the training data on a point-by-point basis, but they do not build internal rules to classify the data in a physical manner.

The best way to overcome this is to reduce the size of the neural network, to avoid having too many redundant degrees-of-freedom that contribute to over-fitting, or to introduce *regularization:*

https://towardsdatascience.com/l1-and-l2-regularization-methods-ce25e7fc831c?gi=519207f1e90d

Also, if you have any hints about a numerical or physical framework that is well-suited for your problem (for example, a special transformation for your input data), you should also consider adding it to the neural network manually. (This is recommeded in most PhD-level courses about machine learning).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Well in that case, if `validation_loss < training_loss `, and the model does not work properly, maybe the loss function seems small, but is actually huge from a physical perspective. Are you sure it's really small? Maybe the physical definition of the loss function, or your accuracy metric has to be changed. The a small loss function is failing to represent a high-quality physical solution, that is bad news for optimization.

Comment: Or maybe there is a bug somewhere, it also happens :)

Comment: By the way, when you define the PCA? Are you sure that the transformations for `X_train` and `X_test` are consistent? Maybe they are transformed into different (types of) orthogonal components, and hence the model is not valid anymore.

Comment: I applied the PCA to the X and then split it into X_train and X_test, so they must be consistent?

Comment: Yeah that sounds good. Your problem is a bit strange, that the validation loss is small, but the modell still under-performs. Check that the metrics and the loss function are physically meaningful. Otherwise, I don' want to say it, but probably there is a bug :)